# How to parse date received from ng-pick-date-time?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using ng-pick-date-time. I need to get date and time from date-time picker input.

Value of date that I receive is 'Mon Sep 30 2019 11:11:54 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)'.

How can I parse this value? Is there a property that sets this value format?

`<input class="text size200 calendarClass" [owlDateTime]="dt1" 
     name="validityPeriodEndDate" formControlName="validityPeriodEndDate" required>
    <span class="trigger calendarClass" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1">
      <img  style="padding-left: 1pt;vertical-align: middle;" src="assets/images/icons/calendar.png" /></span>`

this.validityPeriodEndDate =  this.requestForm.controls.validityPeriodEndDate.value;

Comment: Please post some code that shows a bare minimum of what you've tried so far, or a minimum working example.

Comment: please create a demo in stackbliz

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js for parsing date 
this.validityPeriodEndDate=moment(this.requestForm.controls.validityPeriodEndDate.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

As you using Angular, you can use **two way binding** and bind the value to variable of type **Date**.

Add `[(ngModel)]="dateTime"` to your **input** tag and create a new variable `public dateTime: Date` in the **.ts file**. Now you have the date in correct type, you can utilize the existing methods of **Date**.

I hope this resolves your problem.